# How do I pull Docker Container from Azure Container Registry in Azure Container Instance with Terraform - Error with Credentials

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-container-instances, azure-container-registry

Hy everbody, I'm new to terraform and I'm trying to create a container instance with terraform and pulling an existing container from azure container registry into it. The registry has a private endpint, the envoirenment is private and only reachable via Bastion. I have the issue that azure throws me the error for checking the credentials of the registry, but I checked it a hundred times.

```
Create or update Container Group Thu Aug 04 2022 10:56:42 GMT+0200 (Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit)
New alert rule New support request Summary JSON Change history 
(Preview) Operation name Create or update Container Group
Time stamp Thu Aug 04 2022 10:56:42 GMT+0200 (Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit)
Event initiated by ... 
Error code InaccessibleImage Message The image '..........azurecr.io/web_app:latest' in container group 'aci-test' 
is not accessible. Please check the image and registry credential.
```

Does any one have an idea or know how to solve this problem? Below is the code for the ACI and then the code for the ACR.

```
resource "azurerm_user_assigned_identity" "aci_managed" {
   name                = "test-managed-aci-id"
   resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
   location            = var.location
}
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "acr_managed" {
  scope = var.scope
  role_definition_name = "AcrPull"
  principal_id         = azurerm_user_assigned_identity.aci_managed.principal_id   
  skip_service_principal_aad_check = true
}
resource "azurerm_container_group" "aci" {
  name                = var.name
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  ip_address_type     = "Public"
  dns_name_label      = "aci-first-container01"
  os_type             = "Linux"
  

    container {
        name   = "web-app"
        image  = ".........azurecr.io/web_app:latest"   
        cpu    = "0.5"
        memory = "1.5"

    ports {
        port     = 80
        protocol = "TCP"}
    }

    identity {
        type = "UserAssigned"
        identity_ids = [azurerm_user_assigned_identity.aci_managed.id]
    }


    image_registry_credential {
        server = "...........azurecr.io"
        username = "..........."
        password = "................" 

    }
    depends_on = [azurerm_role_assignment.acr_managed]
}
resource "azurerm_container_registry" "acr" {
    name                          = var.name
    location                      = var.location
    resource_group_name           = var.resource_group_name
    sku                           = var.yaml.acr.private == true ? "Premium" : "Premium" 
    admin_enabled                 = var.yaml.acr.admin_enabled
    public_network_access_enabled = var.yaml.acr.private == true ? ...var.yaml.acr.public_network_access_enabled : true
    network_rule_bypass_option    = "AzureServices"

    dynamic "network_rule_set" {
       for_each = toset(var.yaml.acr.private == true ? [ "Premium" ] : [])
        content {
        default_action = "Deny"

        dynamic "ip_rule" {
          for_each = toset(var.yaml.acr.private == true ? values(var.yaml.ip_whitelisting) : [])
          content {
             action = "Allow"
             ip_range = ip_rule.value
          }
        }
     }
  }

    identity {
        type = "UserAssigned"
        identity_ids = [var.aci_managed_id]
   }

  tags = var.tags
}
resource "azurerm_private_endpoint" "endpoint" {
  for_each = var.yaml.acr.private ? toset(["private"]) : toset([])
  name                = var.pe_name
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.pe_resource_group
  subnet_id           = var.subnet_id

  private_service_connection {
    name                           = "${var.pe_name}-psc"
    private_connection_resource_id = azurerm_container_registry.acr.id
    is_manual_connection           = false
    subresource_names              = ["registry"]
  }

  private_dns_zone_group {
    name = "dns-zone-group-acr"
    private_dns_zone_ids = [var.private_dns_zone_ids]
  }
```

Comment: Would you mind adding the error to the question as well?

Comment: Create or update Container Group
Thu Aug 04 2022 10:56:42 GMT+0200 (Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit)
New alert rule
New support request
Summary
JSON
Change history (Preview)
Operation name
Create or update Container Group
Time stamp
Thu Aug 04 2022 10:56:42 GMT+0200 (Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit)
Event initiated by
...
Error code
InaccessibleImage
Message
The image '..........azurecr.io/web_app:latest' in container group 'aci-test' is not accessible. Please check the image and registry credential.